# How to import image from one ClientBundle to use it in style of another ClientBundle

Tags: css, gwt, clientbundle, cssresource

I have like one client bundle :

```
public interface FirstClientBundle extends ClientBundle {

  public static final FirstClientBundle INSTANCE = 
  GWT.create(FirstClientBundle.class);

  @Source("panel-top-bg.png")
  public ImageResource panelTopBg();
}
```

and I'd like to use image from first Bundle in styles of another Bundle. Something like this:

```
public interface SecondClientBundle extends ClientBundle {

  public static final SecondClientBundle INSTANCE = 
  GWT.create(SecondClientBundle.class);

  public interface Style extends CssResource {
    @ClassName("panelTop")
    String panelTop();
  }

  @Source({ "style.css" })
  public Style style();
}
```

end the CSS file looks like:

```
@sprite .panel-top {
  gwt-image: "FirstClientBundle.panelTopBg";
  height: 18px;
  cursor: move;
}
```

Is it even possible? Or should I do whole thing differently?

Answer (score 0):

Could you write the second `ClientBundle` as a subinterface of the first one?

```
public interface SecondClientBundle extends FirstClientBundle
```

Comment: Ups, there should be SecondClientBundle instance there. And I'd rather not use inheritance in this case, because I should then extend SecondClientBulndle by more than one interface.

Comment: Although its one of solutions, I think it could make code messy.

Comment: I don't get why inheritance is not what you want because it is 'messy'. Can you explain why, or what kind of solution you want?

Comment: I don't think that inheteritance is needed here so I'd like to aviod it. Here it is explained pretty good: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html

Comment: I understand the difference, but I think here you are limited to what GWT can actually do and what it can't do. From http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html: "@sprite is sensitive to the FooBundle in which the CSSResource is declared; a sibling ImageResource method named in the @sprite declaration will be used to compose the background sprite."